# My app doesn't show LiveData<String> into a text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

The LiveData is supposed to print a String in playerOneName text attribute that we took from the TextInputEditText earlier but I tried even in Log.d it shows no result at all.

Here's the code
**ViewModel**

```
class GameViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _playerOne = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val playerOne: LiveData<String> = _playerOne
    private val _playerTwo = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val playerTwo: LiveData<String> = _playerTwo
    private val _playerOneScore = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val playerOneScore: LiveData<Int> = _playerOneScore
    private val _playerTwoScore = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val playerTwoScore: LiveData<Int> = _playerTwoScore

    fun setPlayerOne(name: String) {
        _playerOne.value = name
    }

    fun setPlayerTwo(name: String) {
        _playerTwo.value = name
    }
}
```

**XML** of StartFragment

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/player_one_name"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/player_one_name"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/start_img">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_player_one"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
```

**XML** for GameFragment

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/player_one_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.playerOne.toString()}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**GameFragment**

```
class GameFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentGameBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val sharedViewModel: GameViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentGameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.resetBtn.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_gameFragment_to_startFragment)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.apply {
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
            viewModel = sharedViewModel
            gameFragment = this@GameFragment
        }
        Log.d("GameFragment", "Player One:" + sharedViewModel.playerOne.toString())
    }
}
```

I tried playerOneScore but as i expected the is the same problem here's the code for Log.d in the viewModel class

```
        Log.d("GameViewModel", _playerOneScore.value.toString() + " Score: " + playerOneScore.value)
```

and here's the logcat

```
D/GameViewModel: 0 Score: null
```

Comment: Try without toString() here android:text="@{viewModel.playerOne}" . Also for the Log use like this sharedViewModel.playerOne.value.

Comment: Tried without toString() but still the same problem.

Comment: in xml, u do not need toString(), and in the class, use sharedViewModel.playerOne.value

Comment: Still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the StartFragment.kt you need to override onPause() function so that when you go to the next fragment it saves the name of the the players in the ViewModel.

**StartFragment.kt**

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    var playerOneName: String = binding.editPlayerOne.text.toString()
    sharedViewModel.setPlayerOne(playerOneName)
    var playerTwoName: String = binding.editPlayerTwo.text.toString()
    sharedViewModel.setPlayerTwo(playerTwoName) }
```

For the player's score i did the following

**ViewModel**

```
init {
    resetData()
}
fun playerOneWon() {
    _playerOneScore.value = _playerOneScore.value?.plus(1)
}
fun playerTwoWon() {
    _playerTwoScore.value = _playerTwoScore.value?.plus(1)
fun resetData() {
    _playerOneScore.value = 0
    _playerTwoScore.value = 0 }
```

I used the `playerOneWon()` and `playerTwoWon()` functions to increment the score in the GameFragment.kt and for the xml i used

```
android:text="@{viewModel.playerOneScore.toString()}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following Code I hope your problem will be solved

**Gradle file**

```
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
```

**ViewModel**

```
class GameViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _playerOne = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val playerOne: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_playerOne) { it }  
    private val _playerTwo = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val playerTwo: LiveData<String> =  Transformations.map(_playerTwo) { it }
    private val _playerOneScore = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val playerOneScore: LiveData<Int> = Transformations.map(_playerOneScore) { it }
    private val _playerTwoScore = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val playerTwoScore: LiveData<Int> = Transformations.map(_playerTwoScore) { it }

    fun setPlayerOne(name: String) {
        _playerOne.value = name
    }

    fun setPlayerTwo(name: String) {
        _playerTwo.value = name
    }
}
```

**GameFragment**

```
class GameFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var sharedViewModel: GameViewModel 

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
sharedViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
sharedViewModel.playerOne.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {  
    Log.d("GameFragment", "Player One: $it")
 }

// use this method to change the value
   sharedViewModel.setPlayerOne("Some Player")

}
```

Comment: Still get the same problem, i've edited the question to show the Log.d